# Applying unnest_longer / unlist to a nested list so I can work with ggplot2

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, nested

I have the following question.

I want to work with `ggplot2`. So I found out that for that it is nice to work with the long data format. E.g. each Experiment is added to the Bottom of the data frame and gets a factor variable in a column. The data I have right now is in a nested list with the following structure:

[image: following structure.]

I can not get `unlist` und `unnest_longer` to work. What am I doing wrong?

The top of `str(list)` looks like this:

```
    List of 5
 $ Test        :List of 2
  ..$ Measurement 1:List of 2
  .. ..$ Test1:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  15 variables:
  .. ..$ Test2:'data.frame':    100 obs. of  15 variables:
```

When applying `unlist(list)` I just get a data frame with one column. But I would like to Keep the columns of the lowest Level in the nested list (see structure above)

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Images are not helpful. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RonakShah I hope this is better. This is the very first part of my data:
`dput(list.tests[[1]][[1]][[1]][1:10, 1:4])
structure(list(Time = c(60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 
300, 330), Interval.Time = c(60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 
270, 300, 330), Shear.Rate = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Shear.Strain = c(5250, 8250, 11200, 14200, 17200, 20200, 
    23200, 26200, 29200, 32200)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")` It is just a bunch of lists in lists and I would like to use ggplot2 but cant figure out how